# Ansible loop through group vars in template

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I'm struggling with a pattern pulling inventory vars in Ansible templates, please help. :)

I'm setting up a monitoring server, and I want to be able to automatically provision the servers using Ansible. I'm struggling with loops in the template to allow me to this.

My semi-working soluition so far is in the playbook that calls the template task I have:

monitoringserver.yml

```
 vars:
       servers_to_monitor:
         - {cname: web1, ip_address: 192.168.33.111}
         - {cname: web2, ip_address: 192.168.33.112}
         - {cname: db1, ip_address: 192.168.33.211}
         - {cname: db2, ip_address: 192.168.33.212}
```

template.yml

```
all_hosts += [
           {% for host in servers_to_monitor %}
                   "{{ host.cname }}{{ host.ip }}|cmk-agent|prod|lan|tcp|wato|/" + FOLDER_PATH + "/",
           {% endfor %}
]
```

But this isn't ideal as I can't define different IP address for different servers to be monitoring. How have other people done this? I'm sure it must be trivial but my brain's struggling with the syntax.

Thanks

Alan

edit: To clarify the resulting template looks something like this:

```
all_hosts += [
                        "web1|cmk-agent|prod|lan|tcp|wato|/" + FOLDER_PATH + "/",
                        "web2|cmk-agent|prod|lan|tcp|wato|/" + FOLDER_PATH + "/",
                        "db1|cmk-agent|prod|lan|tcp|wato|/" + FOLDER_PATH + "/",
                        "db2|cmk-agent|prod|lan|tcp|wato|/" + FOLDER_PATH + "/",
]
```

What I would like is the values web1/web2/db1/db2 to be different depending on whether I'm using a production inventory file or a development inventory file.

Comment: Could you add what you want the actual result to be?

Comment: Thanks Ramon, added an edit to clarify :)

Comment: I've kind of managed to work around it now by creating two group_var dirs monitor-dev and monitor-pub then having the playing book use the role all, and the inventory file for production calling the specific group vars. Doesn't seem quite right though :)

Comment: Could you clarify a bit ? You say "I'm setting up a monitoring server", then "different IP address for different monitoring servers" Although it might not matter much, how many servers are you setting up ?.

Also, I don't see IPs in the resulting syntax you present. This is a bit confusing. Where do you need IP addresses ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot :) I've updated the question

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Ideally you would be using different inventory files for production and staging, which would allow you to keep the same `{{ inventory_hostname }}` value, but target different machines.

You can also loop through different groups...

hosts:

```
[web]
web1
web2

[db]
db1
db2
```

playbook:

```
- name: play that sets a group to loop over
  vars:
    servers_to_monitor: "{{ groups['db'] }}"

  tasks:
    - template:
      src: set-vars.j2
      dest: set-vars.js
```

template:

```
all_hosts += [
{% for host in servers_to_monitor %}
  "{{ hostvars[host].inventory_hostname }}{{ hostvars[host].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}|cmk-agent|prod|lan|tcp|wato|/" + FOLDER_PATH + "/",
{% endfor %}
]
```

Comment: Docs for Jinja2 here: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/